# Specifics on how to use matplotlib.colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, colorbar

**Problem:**

I have two columns of data (`x` and `y` points), and a third column with labels (values `0` or `1`). I want to plot `x` and `y` on a scatter plot, and color them according to whether the label is `0` or `1`, and I want a colorbar on the right of the plot.

Here is my data: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ffta3wgrl2vvcpw/data.csv?dl=0

Note: I know that since there are only two labels I will only get two colors despite using a colorbar; but this dataset is just used as an example here.

**What I've done so far**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
import matplotlib as m

#read in the data
with open('data.csv', 'rb') as infile:
    data=[]
    r = csv.reader(infile)
    for row in r:
        data.append(row)

col1, col2, col3 = [el for el in zip(*data)]

#I'd like to have a colormap going from red to green:
cdict = {
'red'  :  ( (0.0, 0.25, 0), (0.5, 1, 1), (1., 0.0, 1.)),
'green':  ( (0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (0.5, 0.0, 0.0), (1., 1.0, 1.0)),
'blue' :  ( (0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (1, 0.0, 0.0), (1., 0.0, 0.0))}

cm = m.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap('my_colormap', cdict)

# I got the following line from an example I saw; it works for me,
# but I don't really know how it works as an input to colorbar,
# and would like to know.
formatter = plt.FuncFormatter(lambda i, *args: ['0', '1'][int(i)])

plt.figure()
plt.scatter(col1, col2, c=col3)
plt.colorbar(ticks=[0, 1], format=formatter, cmap=cm)
```

The above code doesn't work because of the call to `plt.colorbar`.

1. How can I make it work (what is missing), and is this the best way to do it?
2. The documentation on what the `ticks` parameter is is incomprehensible to me. What is it exactly?

   Documentation: http://matplotlib.org/api/figure_api.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure.colorbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `col3` to scatter as an array of floats, not a tuple, and not ints

So, this should work:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv
import matplotlib as m
import numpy as np

#read in the data
with open('data.csv', 'rb') as infile:
    data=[]
    r = csv.reader(infile)
    for row in r:
    data.append(row)

col1, col2, col3 = [el for el in zip(*data)]

#I'd like to have a colormap going from red to green:
cdict = {
    'red'  :  ( (0.0, 1.0, 1.0), (0.5, 0.0, 0.0), (1.0, 0.0, 0.0)),
    'green':  ( (0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (0.5, 0.0, 0.0), (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)),
    'blue' :  ( (0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (1.0, 0.0, 0.0), (1.0, 0.0, 0.0))}  

cm = m.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap('my_colormap', cdict)

#I got the following line from an example I saw; it works for me, but I don't really know how it works as an input to colorbar, and would like to know.
formatter = plt.FuncFormatter(lambda i, *args: ['0', '1'][int(i)])

plt.figure()
plt.scatter(col1, col2, c=np.asarray(col3,dtype=np.float32),lw=0,cmap=cm)
plt.colorbar(ticks=[0, 1], format=formatter, cmap=cm)
```

As for `ticks`, you are passing a list of where you want ticks on the colorbar. So, in your example, you have a tick at 0 and a tick at 1.

I've also fixed your cmap, to go from red to green. You need to tell scatter to use the cmap too.

[image]